# Update a value in react based on the url pathname change

Tags: reactjs, path

So here is the situation. I have a Navbar component, which has a title, and I have a few routes with different pathnames, let's say /path1, /path2, and /path3. What I want to achieve, is that every route I visit, I expect to see a different title for App bar.

In my appbar component, I tried this:

const [appBarTitle, setAppBarTitle] = useState('');

```
>     function listenToPopstate() {
>       if(window.location.pathname === '/path1') {
>       setAppBarTitle('/path1')
>     } else if(window.location.pathname === '/path2') {
>       setAppBarTitle('/path2')
>     }}
```

Then, I am using this function

```
> useEffect(() => {   window.addEventListener('popstate',
> listenToPopstate);   listenToPopstate();   return () =>
> window.removeEventListener('popstate', listenToPopstate); }, [])
```

And then I am passing the value to AppBar component as a title.

Expected behavior: Update app bar title after every reroute.
Actual behavior: it does only after I refresh the page.

I was trying to understand, is there anything like onhashchange, for pathname change. So I don't know how to proceed.

Would appreciate any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably take advantage of the `useLocation` hook from [`react-router-dom`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/).

[Here's a link](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-microservice-s3sot?file=/src/App.js) to an example of what you're looking for.

Basically what you can do is use the `pathname` key from `useLocation` hook to determine what route you're on. And using the `pathname` as a key from the `PAGE_TITLES` object, return the updated title from that.

```
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const PAGE_TITLES = {
  "/": "This is the Home page",
  "/child": "Welcome to the Child page"
};

function NavBar() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return (
    <ul>
      <h1>Page: {PAGE_TITLES[pathname]}</h1>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/child">Child</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There might be a misunderstanding. I need to display not the currentPath, but just different names for my Appbar Title. For example: We go to /path1, app title would be like: Path 1, we go to /path2, and it is:  Welcome to Path 2 and so on.

Comment: Do you have a list of all the page titles? If you did you could just use a switch statement along with the above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This doesn't solve my problem, but I appreciate the help :)

Comment: No worries, I've updated the snippet if that helps. But if not, not quite sure what you need :)

Comment: So look, I need the same thing, my links are called like this let's say, but when I go to another route, I don't need a name of the link, but something different as a title. LEt's say, when I go to Home, I want the title to be Hello Nice Home, and when I go to Child, I want it to be for example  Welcome to 2022)

Comment: Not sure how my code doesn't do that? [Check the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-microservice-s3sot?file=/src/App.js), unless I'm seriously misunderstanding what you need.

Comment: I fixed it, needed to do some modification to the code, your approach worked, thanks!